# Publish to facebook wall using FBSDKShareDialog does not need Submit for Review?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

I have an app which will publish a post to fb wall using the FBSDKShareDialog. My code is such as below:

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        //TODO: process error or result.
        if (!error) {
            FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
            content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com"];

            FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
            dialog.delegate = self;
            dialog.shareContent = content;

            [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:self];}}];
```

My question is do I need to Submit for Review to request for publish_actions if I just publish using this Share Dialog. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not even need `publish_actions` to share via the dialog in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the clarification then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to submit your app for review if you only use a dialog. Only if you are calling the API directly, and the endpoint you are using requires an extended permission, you will have to submit for review.